# 'react-native link' working for some and not for anothers packages

Tags: react-native, npm-install

Why 'react-native link' works for some packages like 'react-native-vector-icons', but for others it just don't link the packages?
Is there any way I can manually solve this?

Sublime editor - green: packages linked, red: packages not linked

[image]

When linking fails, it does not show any error message:

[image]

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.55.1

npm: 5.6.0

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Im having the same issue with react-native-amap3d

Comment: I'm not quite sure what I did at that time, but you can check in your package.json file if your libs are correctly writen. You can try to use some wildcards just before package version, like chaging "react-native-menu-button": "1.0.0" to "react-native-menu-button": "^1.0.0" to get the lastest update from libs